# Check if feature attribute is empty in QGIS with Python

Tags: pyqgis

I want my Python script to do something when two feature attribute values are `None` at the same time.

So I made this `if` statement: `if feature["Name"] and feature["Zon"] is None:`, but the code stops there and doesn't continue. Before the `if` statement I print both feature attribute values and get the following: `(None, None)`. So the code should theoretically work, but it doesn't. What am I missing?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need to explicitly state the condition twice so you could use:

```
if feature["Name"] is None and feature["Zon"] is None:
    # do something
```